# вывести на экран в алфавитном порядке все слова строки, в которых есть четыре подряд идущие согласные буквы

Tags: строки, циклы, pascal, pascalabc.net

вот мой код. я не знаю, как обратиться к элементам строкового массива. в первой строке выдает ошибку "ожидался тип".

```
var a: array ['б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'ж', 'з', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ'] of string;
    s:string;
    i:byte;
begin
    write('строка: ');
    readln(s);
    for i:=1 to length(s) do
      if mas[i] in mas then
        if mas[i+1] in mas then
          if mas[i+2] in mas then
            if mas[i+3] in mas then
              writeln(mas[i]);
end.
```

Comment: Ну обидно компилятору, что в секции задания типов Вы пытаетесь ещё и значения указать...

Comment: и как это исправить?...

Comment: 1. Попробуйте определить `a` как `const a: array[0..N] of char = ('б', ... );`, где N - кол-во символов;
2. Попробуйте определить `a` как `set of ('б', 'в', ...)` и использовать `if ( mas[i] in a )`;
3. Можно попробовать обойтись без массива, строкой: `const a = 'бвг...'`, и использовать что-то вроде `if ( a.Contains(mas[i]) )` или подобную функцию.
4. Цикл укоротите, т.к. по достижении `length(s)` произойдёт выход за пределы массива.

Comment: P.S. Полагаю, Вы собирались проверить `s[i] in a`. Об этом мой п.4

Comment: я не могу укоротить цикл, так как надо проверить первые 4 элемента (буквы в слове). вот в питоне можно было написать and, а тут не знаю как

Comment: @kan3k1k3n, Если проверяется `s[i]` на вхождение в диапазон `a`, то надо написать `for i := 1 to length(s) - 3`, потому что если идти до `length(s)`, то в итоге получится `s[length(s) + 1]`, что выходит за границы строки. И да, `and` тоже можно, только в скобки оборачивать:
`if (s[i] in a) and (s[i+1] in a) and ...`
В принципе, можно, наверное, даже рекурсию применить, но не знаю насколько это оправданно в данном случае.

Comment: @kan3k1k3n Как вариант, для данной задачи можно ещё попробовать RegExp применить (если PascalABC их поддерживает). В качестве разминки. Громоздко, правда, получится.

Answer (score 1):

Все предложенные мной в комментариях способы работают. Причём, меняется только объявление набора согласных.

```
program test;

uses
  System.Text.RegularExpressions;

function CheckWordByArray(const s: string): Boolean;
const
  consonants: array[00..20] of char =
    ('б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'ж', 'з', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ');

begin
  Result := s.length > 3;
  if ( not Result ) then Exit();

  for var i := 1 to length(s) - 3 do begin

    Result :=     ( consonants.contains( s[i+0] ) )
              and ( consonants.contains( s[i+1] ) )
              and ( consonants.contains( s[i+2] ) )
              and ( consonants.contains( s[i+3] ) );
{}
{
    Result :=     ( s[i+0] in consonants )
              and ( s[i+1] in consonants )
              and ( s[i+2] in consonants )
              and ( s[i+3] in consonants );
{}
    if ( Result ) then Exit();
  end;
end;

function CheckWordByString(const s: string): Boolean;
const
  consonants = 'бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщ';

begin
  Result := s.length > 3;
  if ( not Result ) then Exit();

  for var i := 1 to length(s) - 3 do begin
{
    Result :=     ( consonants.contains( s[i+0] ) )
              and ( consonants.contains( s[i+1] ) )
              and ( consonants.contains( s[i+2] ) )
              and ( consonants.contains( s[i+3] ) );
{}

    Result :=     ( s[i+0] in consonants )
              and ( s[i+1] in consonants )
              and ( s[i+2] in consonants )
              and ( s[i+3] in consonants );
{}
    if ( Result ) then Exit();
  end;
end;

function CheckWordBySet(const s: string): Boolean;
const
  consonants = ['б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'ж', 'з', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ'];

begin
  Result := s.length > 3;
  if ( not Result ) then Exit();

  for var i := 1 to length(s) - 3 do begin
{
    Result :=     ( consonants.contains( s[i+0] ) )
              and ( consonants.contains( s[i+1] ) )
              and ( consonants.contains( s[i+2] ) )
              and ( consonants.contains( s[i+3] ) );
{}

    Result :=     ( s[i+0] in consonants )
              and ( s[i+1] in consonants )
              and ( s[i+2] in consonants )
              and ( s[i+3] in consonants );
{}
    if ( Result ) then Exit();
  end;
end;

function CheckWordByRegEx(const s: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Regex.IsMatch(s, '[бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщ]{4}');
//  Result := Regex.IsMatch(s, '[^аеёиоуыэюя]{4}');
end;

function CheckWordOther(const s: string): Boolean;
const
  vowels = 'аеёиоуыэюя';

begin
  var counter: Byte := 0;
   
  foreach var c: char in s do begin
    if ( vowels.contains(c) ) then
      counter := 0
    else
      Inc(counter);

    if ( counter > 3 ) then Break;
  end;

  Result := counter > 3;
end;

procedure DoTest(const s: string; const expected: Boolean);
begin
  Assert(CheckWordByArray(s)  = expected);
  Assert(CheckWordByString(s) = expected);
  Assert(CheckWordBySet(s)    = expected);
  Assert(CheckWordByRegEx(s)  = expected);
  Assert(CheckWordOther(s)    = expected);
end;

begin
  DoTest('строка',    false);
  DoTest('контрмера', true );
  DoTest('к',         false);

  WriteLn('Press Enter.');
  ReadLn();
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a: array of string  = ...
```

Как это точно записывается в вашем абэце, и можно ли там в var инициализировать динамический массив, я не знаю .

А то, что вы пытались написать, может при доработке быть интерпретировано как массив строк, индексированный символами из множества. Нужно это или нет - по коду, в котором `a` не используется - непонятно, но очень сомнительно.

Comment: пишет "Нельзя преобразовать тип set of char к array of string"

Comment: посмотрите, как у вас задаются константы-массивы. В Delphi  - с круглыми скобками. Но главное - я думаю, вам нафиг этот массив не нужен. Может быть, множество символов или просто одна строка подойдёт лучше.

Answer (score 0):

```
##  // PasscalАВС.NЕТ 3.8.3
var Согласные := 'бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщ';
var a := ReadlnString('строка: ').ToWords;
var regexp := '.*[' + Согласные + ']{4,}.*';
a.Where(w -> w.IsMatch(regexp)).Print
```